# django app with ajax for processing dataframe

Tags: jquery, json, django, ajax, dataframe

I am trying to show busy indicator image as soon as the user uploads an excel file . While the file process is done, I would like to replace the image with processed table.
Problem:

1. The ajax success block is not executing(alert message inside success block is not working)
2. The uploaded data is converted to json but unable to convert back to dataframe for processing.

The code that gets executed on upload button click in views.py

```
def indicator(request):
    excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
    uploaded_data = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    df_json = uploaded_data.to_json()
    
return render(request,'myapp/indicator.html',{'df':df_json})
```

indicator.html:

```
<script>
    var dataframe = JSON.parse("{{df|escapejs}}");
    var replace_data = function(data){
        alert('successs')
        $('#success').append(data.list_of_jsonstuffs);
        $('#loading').remove()
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/processing/',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataframe),
            success: function(data){
                alert('ajax done')
                replace_data(data)
            }


        })
    })

    </script>
```

The function in view that triggers and does the processing.

```
@csrf_exempt
def processing_file(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        excel_file1 = json.dumps(request.GET)
        e1 = json.loads(excel_file1)
        input_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([e1])
        print(input_df.shape)
        processed = gen.generate_output_columns(excel_file)
        output_validation = processed[const.OUTPUTCOLUMNSWITHVALIDATION]
        excel_data = output_validation.values.tolist()
        return excel_data
```

The input_df is 1 by 2 however uploaded excel is 17 by 55. Somewhere in JSON Stringify and json loads the structure is getting changed but when I try with POST I was once able to succeed with processing but success block never gets executed. Could someone help me understand what's wrong with my json to dataframe parsing and ajax success in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve loading animation on a django app using Ajax POST instead of Ajax GET. Posting the code in case this shows up in search results.

fileprocessed.html

```
    <script>
        var dataframe = JSON.parse("{{df|escapejs}}");
        var replace_data = function(data){
            $('#loading').remove()
            $('#load_processed').DataTable({
                columns:[
                    {title:'col1'},
                    {title:'col2'},
                    {title:'col3'},
                    {title:'col4'},
                    {title:'col5'},
                    {title:'col6'},
                    {title:'col7'},
                    {title:'col8'},
                    {title:'col9'},
                    {title:'col10'},
                    {title:'col11'},
                    {title:'col12'},
                    {title:'col13'},
                    {title:'col14'},
                    {title:'col15'},
                    {title:'col16'},
                    {title:'col17'},
                    {title:'col18'},
                    {title:'col19'},
                    {title:'col20'}
                ],
                data: data
            });
    
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/processing/',
                type:'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataframe),
                success: function(data){
                    replace_data(data)
                }
            })
        })
        </script>
<div id="loading">
<div id="img_div">
    {%  load static %}<img src="{%  static  "/img/hourGlass.gif" %}" alt="Hour Glass image, processing"/></div>
    <p><b>Loading....</b></p>
</div>
<div id="success">
<table id="load_processed" class="display" width="100%">

</table>
```

The function that gets triggered when user clicks UI button,

```
def busy_indicator(request):
    excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
    uploaded_data = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    df_json = uploaded_data.to_json()
    return render(request,'myapp/file_processed.html',{'df':df_json})
```

The ajax calls the below function(url /processing shown in above ajax post code),

```
@csrf_exempt
def processing_file(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        e1 = json.loads(request.body) #parses incoming json data
        input_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e1) #converts to df as my process script 
                                              #requires dataframe input
        processed = gen.generate_output_columns(input_df) 
        output_validation = processed[const.OUTPUTCOLUMNSWITHVALIDATION]
        excel_data = output_validation.values.tolist()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(excel_data), content_type='application/json')#sends 
                   #back json to ajax
```